# How to read from excel in a specific encoding?

Tags: c#, excel, encoding

I copied from an excel file to a txt file the column names. I read from the txt file the following way:

```
CultureInfo cultureHU;
Encoding encodingHU;
cultureHU = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hu-HU");
encodingHU = Encoding.GetEncoding(cultureHU.TextInfo.ANSICodePage);
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("settings.txt", encodingHU, true))
{
...
}
```

**How do I read from an Excel file with the same encoding?** If I do it the default way (xlRange.Cells[1, i].Value.ToString()), then I get wrong values:

- in the excel and txt file I have: "Szerzõdõ"
- reading from the text file in *encodingHU* encoding I get: "Szerződő" (this is the correct format)
- reading from excel in C# i get: "Szerzõdõ"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the bad string to the correct encoding like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(encodingHU.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I used ExcelDataReader. I needed coding 1250

```
ExcelReaderConfiguration conf = new ExcelReaderConfiguration();
conf.FallbackEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250);

using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream, conf))
{
...
}
```